# Understanding Laravel's Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to wrap my head around pagination based on [what I've read](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination).

I've never done pagination before so excuse my lack of knowledge. Based on the documentation, I do not see how to get the next page's data. I'm using a client-side (js) library.

Backend Model:

```php
return User::where('col', $value)->paginate(15);
```

The above gave me [this json](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json).

Based on the data available: `from`, `last_page` etc, what should I pass to the backend to get, say, page 2? From the json I can get page 2 but how to query for page 2? Something like this would make sense:

```php
return User::where('col', $value)->paginate(15)->nextPage(2);
```

My understanding of `paginate` is so show the amount of items per page.

Doing this in raw sql is doable:

```sql
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15
```

To elaborate, here's my controller:

```php
public function all()
{
  $customers =  ( new Customer )->getCustomers();

  if ($customers) {
    return response()->json($customers, 200);
  }

  return response()->json([], 200);
}
```

Comment: I don’t think you’re supposed to do anything much yourself in this regard - you just use the URLs provided in the response, to request the data for a different page … `first_page_url`, `last_page_url`, `next_page_url` and `prev_page_url` exist in that response for a reason, presumably.

Comment: I've shown how my controller looks. Are you saying I need to write my own pagination in raw sql? I make api requests to that `all()` function.

Comment: No, I am saying _use_ the data you have already been provided with in the output. The URLs you need to request to get to certain pages, are already in there … So, go and request these URLs then.

Comment: Try to pass 'page' get data: `yourpage.com/api/getData?page=2`

Comment: You don’t need to do anything manually here - `->paginate(15)` handles _all_ there is to do in this regard for you already, that includes taking the passed page parameter into account when it comes to selecting the correct 15 records to return.

Comment: Holy smokes you all are correct. I should have tried to append `page=2` before coming here. My apologies. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can paginate resources using laravels default pagination inputs.

You don't have to do ->nextPage() or something just send `page` input and laravel will handle rest of it.

like this;

```
http://example.com/posts?page=2;
```

I aggree, [Laravel Pagination Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination) is not beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could configure like this:

```
$users = Users::all()->paginate(5);
return view('users.index',compact('users'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
```

This will return 5 records per page. Configure by your needs.

In you index file, do something like:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th>no</th>
        <th>user id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->user_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    @endforeach
</table>

{!! $users->links() !!}
```